# sublime text only show the html file in the preview browser and don't do anything with the <script> js file

Tags: javascript, browser, sublimetext3, preview

Sublime text preview in browser doesn't show the javascript that is  in html. when I want to check and see it in chrome browser, it shows the html and css but doesn't do anything with js file. The code is very simple and it works (example in JSBin). (Html and js file in the same directory.)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Practice the Basics - Two overlapping squares sample solution</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
        <script src="rajzos.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>




var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

  var size = 100;

  var positionX = canvasWidth / 2 - size * 0.75;
  var positionY = canvasHeight / 2 - size * 0.75;


  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,.5)';
  context.fillRect(positionX, positionY, size, size);

  positionX += size / 2;
  positionY += size / 2;
```

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting the files properly? Can you provide your actual code?

Comment: I put the code in the question. But I think I connected the files as it supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what should be the expected output but the `script` tag should be in the `head` of your `html`.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
  var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

  var size = 100;

  var positionX = canvasWidth / 2 - size * 0.75;
  var positionY = canvasHeight / 2 - size * 0.75;


  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,.5)';
  context.fillRect(positionX, positionY, size, size);

  positionX += size / 2;
  positionY += size / 2;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Practice the Basics - Two overlapping squares sample solution</title>
         <script src="rajzos.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="450" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. I tried in the head, in the body section same result.

Comment: This is incorrect. Some scripts should be placed just before `</body>` so that they run only after all the elements of the page have been loaded.

Comment: @MattDMo yes, definitely but for such an easy task it could be also in the 'head'.  In any case the problem here most probably is with an incorrect path as we don't know his/her file tree.